# perfect forwarding, variadic template, initializer_list - together

Tags: c++11

gcc 4.8.1 & clang 3.3, c++11 feature complete,
I need to forward args in some function that constructs elements like make_shared/c++14 make_unique. But I have problem with type deduction/forwarding initializer lists/arrays

I need working example of `foo * foo3{ make_it<foo>( {{1,1},{ 10,10 }}, 10 ) };`, so `std::initializer_list` will deduce it arguments and function will forward them

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

struct foo
  {
  struct pairs{ int a,b; };

  foo( int value ){}
  foo( std::initializer_list<pairs> elems, int value ){}
  };

//some custom allocation mechanizm
char store[sizeof(foo)*2];
char * store_ptr = &store[0];
void * allocfromstore( size_t sz ) { void * ret = store_ptr; store_ptr+= sz; return ret; }


template<typename ValueType, typename ArrType, typename... Args>
ValueType * make_it(std::initializer_list<ArrType> il, Args&&... args)
{
  ValueType * obj = new (allocfromstore(sizeof(ValueType))) ValueType( il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return obj;
}


template<typename ValueType, typename... Args>
ValueType * make_it(Args&&... args)
{
  ValueType * obj = new (allocfromstore(sizeof(ValueType))) ValueType( std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return obj;
}
std::initializer_list<foo::pairs> encapsulate( std::initializer_list<foo::pairs> il ){ return il; }
int main(){

  foo * foo0{ make_it<foo>( 10 ) };
  foo * foo1{ make_it<foo>( std::initializer_list<foo::pairs>({{1,1},{ 10,10 }}), 10 ) };
  foo * foo2{ make_it<foo>( encapsulate({{1,1},{ 10,10 }}), 10 ) };
  foo * foo3{ make_it<foo>( {{1,1},{ 10,10 }}, 10 ) };
return 0;
}
```

actually foo3 will fail with clang 3.3:

```
test.cpp:37:15: error: no matching function for call to 'make_it'
  foo * foo3{ make_it<foo>( {{1,1},{ 10,10 }}, 10 ) };
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:18:13: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'ArrType'
ValueType * make_it(std::initializer_list<ArrType> il, Args&&... args)
            ^
test.cpp:26:13: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were     provided
ValueType * make_it(Args&&... args)
            ^
1 error generated.
```

and with gcc 4.8.1:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:37:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_it(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, int)’
   foo * foo3{ make_it<foo>( {{1,1},{ 10,10 }}, 10 ) };
                                                   ^
test.cpp:37:51: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:18:13: note: template<class ValueType, class ArrType, class ... Args>  ValueType* make_it(std::initializer_list<ArrType>, Args&& ...)
 ValueType * make_it(std::initializer_list<ArrType> il, Args&&... args)
             ^
test.cpp:18:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:37:51: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘ArrType’
   foo * foo3{ make_it<foo>( {{1,1},{ 10,10 }}, 10 ) };
                                                   ^
test.cpp:26:13: note: ValueType* make_it(Args&& ...) [with ValueType = foo; Args = {}]
     ValueType * make_it(Args&&... args)
                 ^
test.cpp:26:13: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 5):

Uniform initialization does not work with *forwarding*. You can't forward initialization parameters (directly) and then use those to initialize some object. You can initialize a parameter of a function and then forward that along to someone else, but you can't forward initialization parameters.

Braced-init-lists (aka: the `{}` stuff) do not participate in template argument deduction. That's why your `foo3` gets an error when you do it. The compiler can't know what type you want it converted into, so it fails.

Even if you tried to store `{{1, 1}, {10, 10}}` in an `auto` variable, you wouldn't get what you want. `auto` can type-deduce braced-init-lists into `initializer_list` types, but you'd get something like `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>`.

The compiler simply is not going to go through your template code and figure out what type you really meant.

Comment: But I wondered why it can't work with unnamed struct , excalty in way as constructor works.

initializer_list<some_unnamed_struct>

Comment: @ArturBac There is no way a compiler can tell if `{{0,0},{1,1}}` is `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>`, or `std::initializer_list<std::complex<int>>`, or `std::intializer_list<foo::pairs>`, ...

Comment: yes, I know that it cannot determine that it is struct, so it is a hole in perfect forwarding logic, I was designed to forward arguments for constructors, and there are cases where it cannot be used.

This works, if we tell compiler that is named struct (enough is to name only first struct in list) :
foo * foo3{ make_it<foo>( {foo::pairs{1,1},{ 10,10 }}, 10 ) };

Comment: @ArturBac: "*so it is a hole in perfect forwarding logic*" Perfect forwarding refers to forwarding *objects*. A braced-init-list is not an object; it's an initializer *for* an object, but it's not an object until something has been constructed. "*enough is to name only first struct in list*" That assumes that braced-init-lists can only be used for *lists* of things. They can be used for much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Is a solution that only works for lists of `foo::pairs` acceptable?

```
template<typename ValueType, typename... Args>
ValueType * make_it(std::initializer_list<foo::pairs> il, Args&&... args)
{
  ValueType * obj = new (allocfromstore(sizeof(ValueType))) ValueType( il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one I know, I wondered if deduction of argument std::initializer list could work with unnamed struct as argument.