# Brace-enclosed initializer list works for constructor but not for make_unique

Tags: c++, sfml, unique-ptr

I am struggling to understand why `make_unique<T>` does not accept a Brace-enclosed initializer list, when the constructor of `T` works fine with them.

I am using SFML and creating an instance of `RenderWindow`. `RenderWindow` takes a `VideoMode` instance as its first parameter. The constructor for `VideoMode` takes 3 arguments (the last one optional) and I was successfully able to pass a braced-initializer in its place:

```
sf::RenderWindow window({w_width, w_height}, title);
```

I later tried to create a `unique_ptr` using `make_unique`. The standard says that the arguments to `make_unique` are forwarded to the constructor of the template parameter so I thought the following should work:

```
auto window = std::make_unique<RenderWindow>({w_width, w_height}, title);
```

But unfortunately, I get the following compiler error using GCC 5.1.1.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘make_unique(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, const char* const&)’
 auto window_ptr = std::make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>({w_width, w_height}, title);
```

I guess I've miss-understood the subtleties make_unique, but I couldn't find a clear answer as why the make_unique code above doesn't work.

Please can someone shed some light on this for me?

Cheers

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12431495/

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18001305/